# Apple Accelerate Framework scale and normalize a vector

Tags: ios, macos, math, accelerate-framework

What functions can I use in `Accelerate.framework` to scale a vector by a scalar, and normalize a vector? I found one I think might work for scaling in the documentation but I am confused about it's operation.

```
vDSP_vsma
Vector scalar multiply and vector add; single precision.

void vDSP_vsma (
   const float *__vDSP_A,
   vDSP_Stride __vDSP_I,
   const float *__vDSP_B,
   const float *__vDSP_C,
   vDSP_Stride __vDSP_K,
   float *__vDSP_D,
   vDSP_Stride __vDSP_L,
   vDSP_Length __vDSP_N
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to normalize a vector in-place is something like

```
int n = 3;
float v[3] = {1, 2, 3};
cblas_sscal(n, 1.0 / cblas_snrm2(n, v, 1), v, 1);
```

You'll need to

```
#include <cblas.h>
```

or

```
#include <vblas.h>
```

(or both). Note that several of the functions are in the "matrix" section when they operate on vectors.

If you want to use the vDSP functions, see the [Vector-Scalar Division](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009464) section. There are several things you can do:

- `vDSP_dotpr()`, `sqrt()`, and `vDSP_vsdiv()`
- `vDSP_dotpr()`, `vrsqrte_f32()`, and `vDSP_vsmul()` (`vrsqrte_f32()` is a NEON GCC built-in, though, so you need to check you're compiling for armv7).
- `vDSP_rmsqv()`, multiply by `sqrt(n)`, and `vDSP_vsdiv()`

The reason why there isn't a vector-normalization function is because the "vector" in vDSP means "lots of things at once" (up to around `4096`/`8192`) and necessarily the "vector" from linear algebra. It's pretty meaningless to normalize a `1024`-element vector, and a quick function for normalizing a `3`-element vector isn't something that will make your app significantly faster, which is why there isn't one.

The intended usage of vDSP is more like normalizing `1024` `2`- or `3`-element vectors. I can spot a handful of ways to do this:

- Use `vDSP_vdist()` to get a vector of lengths, followed by `vDSP_vdiv()`. You have to use `vDSP_vdist()` multiple times for vectors of length greater than 2, though.
- Use `vDSP_vsq()` to square all the inputs, `vDSP_vadd()` multiple times to add all of them, the equivalent of `vDSP_vsqrt()` or `vDSP_vrsqrt()`, and `vDSP_vmul()` or `vDSP_vdiv()` as appropriate. It shouldn't be too hard to write the equivalent of `vDSP_vsqrt()` or `vDSP_vrsqrt()`.
- Various ways which pretend your input is a complex vector. Not likely to be faster.

Of course, if you don't have 1024 vectors to normalize, don't overcomplicate things.

Notes:

1. I don't use "2-vector" and "3-vector" to avoid confusion with the "four-vector" from relativity.
2. A good choice of *n* is one that nearly fills your L1 data cache. It's not difficult; they've been relatively fixed at `32K` for around a decade or more (they may be shared between virtual cores in a hyperthreaded CPU and some older/cheaper processors might have 16K), so the most you should do is around `8192` for in-place operation on floats. You might want to subtract a little for stack space, and if you're doing several sequential operations you probably want to keep it all in cache; `1024` or `2048` seem pretty sensible and any more will probably hit diminishing returns. If you care, measure performance...

Comment: Ok thanks for information. I recently watched an apple video where they said the same thing that its good for thousands of elements in a vector to normalize and its like 10x faster then normal code. They also did 3 element vectors like I use with speeds of 2x faster. So I guess I will skip the normalization. Thanks for the help.

Comment: They did a 3-element dot-product; that's only one step in normalization.

Comment: @Justin: If this is a feature that you'd really like to have, please file a bug to request it.  However, please be aware that no library function will ever beat a well-written inline operation on short vectors.

Comment: @Stephen: Of course not, but your "well-written" inline function has to use the "NEON" instructions/vector types, plus (if you don't mind a small loss of accuracy) the "fast reciprocal square-root estimate", which is much faster than 1/sqrt(x).

Comment: @tc: I hope you're referring to the vrsqrte instruction, and not the horrible hack that typically goes by that name.  =)

Comment: @Stephen: `vrsqrte` (presumably used by the `vrsqrte_f32()` builtin I mentioned) probably does the same horrible hack.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It is (a) implemented in hardware and is more efficient (b) uses a lookup, not a linear approximation in floating-point encoding space and (c) is somewhat more accurate.  (and yes, `vrsqrte_f32` is the intrinsic for `vrsqrte`)