# How to compute the square root of a vector elementwise using vDSP / Accelerate in swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, accelerate-framework

I have a vector similar to `[Float](repeating: 1.0, count: 42000)`, and I would like to compute the square root of each element using the Accelerate framework, but no `vDSP_vsqrt` function exists contrary to what is stated in [Apple Accelerate Framework scale and normalize a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251716/apple-accelerate-framework-scale-and-normalize-a-vector). How should I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vForce Swift overlay makes the syntax a little simpler:

```
vForce.sqrt(vector: AccelerateBuffer)
```

Take a look at: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Accelerate/vForce_Operations.swift

...and...

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/718/

Comment: And if it helps anybody else, `AccelerateBuffer` can just be a `[Float]` array

Answer (score 2):

It seems the right function to call is `vvsqrtf` from `vForce`.

Here is the exemple from [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1470491-vvsqrtf) for its usage:

```
var x: [Float] = [100, 10000, 64, 144]
var y = [Float](repeating: 0, count: x.count)
var n = Int32(x.count)

vvsqrtf(&y, &x, &n)

print(y) // [10.0, 100.0, 8.0, 12.0]
```

Notice you can also compute the square root "in place" :

```
var data = [Float](repeating: 25.0, count: input.count)
let n = Int32(data.count)

vvsqrtf(&data, data, &n)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making helper functions to wrap `vvsqrtf`, to expose a more Swift-friendly API:

```
import Accelerate

extension Array where Element == Float {
    func squareRootedElements() -> [Float] {
        if self.isEmpty { return [] }

        var output = Array(repeating: 0, count: self.count)
        var count = Int32(self.count)

        vvsqrtf(&output, self, &count)

        return output
    }

    mutating func squareRootElements() {
        if self.isEmpty { return }

        var count = Int32(self.count)

        vvsqrtf(&self, self, &count)
    }
}

var squares = stride(from: 0 as Float, through: 10, by: +1).map { $0 * $0 }
print(squares)
print(squares.squareRootedElements())
```

Comment: No need for buffer pointer juggling, just `vvsqrtf(&output, self, &count)`

Comment: @MartinR That only works if you mark the function `mutating`

Comment: Well, it compiles for me :) – Note that I passed `self`, not `&self`.

Comment: ohhh, interesting. I'm really not a fan of these implicit conversions T_T

Comment: Beware your function is allocating, so you also have to consider it will be slower compared to an inplace call. :)

Comment: @JeremyCochoy Oh, if you use the same buffer for the first and second param of `vvsqrtf`, would it overwrite in-place?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Yes it does. (I checked on emulator just to be sure ;) ) This is a common behavior expected from C function. If the input addr equal the output addr the operation should happen on place. Otherwise, the documentation should explicitely tell that source and destination should not overlap.

Comment: That's neat. So there could be a second variant. I might call them `squaredElements` and `squareElements`

Comment: @JeremyCochoy Updated :)

Comment: You use the Accelerate framework to make things faster. Wrapper functions and making things faster doesn't go together well.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's just not true. The only overhead incurred here is the constant-time overhead of a function call, which can even be in-lined if you're concerned. It's doing the same things you would otherwise be doing to call `vvsqrtf` yourself, but with less copy/paste

Comment: Furthermore, your premise is a little misguided. You use accelerate to speed up parallelisable operations. Its value-add is that it can use SIMD instructions in the CPU or GPU to speed up your code, which has a speed up factor proportional to your data size. Its value-add isn't the removal of the overhead of a single swift function call (let alone the fact that such overhead is O(1) in the data's size).